# Can't install appmetrics with npm

Tags: npm

I'm trying to install [access-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/access-watch) with no success.
After cloning the repo I call `npm i` and I get the following error. It appears to occur when the installation process tries to install appmetrics. So I tried `npm i appmetrics` and got the exact same error, hence the title of this question.

Here's the tail of the trace,

```
$ cd access-watch
$ npm i
/home/gandalf/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.0/include/node/v8.h:6482:46: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Release/obj.target/appmetrics/geni/appmetrics.cpp: At global scope:
Release/obj.target/appmetrics/geni/appmetrics.cpp:641:13: warning: ‘bool isAppMetricsFile(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static bool isAppMetricsFile(std::string expected, std::string potentialMatch) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:282: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/appmetrics/geni/appmetrics.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/appmetrics/geni/appmetrics.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/gandalf/access-watch/node_modules/appmetrics/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-66-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/gandalf/access-watch/node_modules/appmetrics
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appmetrics@4.0.1 install: `node extract_all_binaries.js || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appmetrics@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gandalf/.npm/_logs/2021-10-11T13_41_15_454Z-debug.log
```

And here's the full thing: https://pastebin.com/cYsHa1EP

I know `node-gyp` must be installed and it is:

```
$ node-gyp --version
v8.2.0
```

I found an [issue](https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues/641) in appmetric's github and ran with CC=gcc-9 but to no success.

Thanks!